# Easier way to represent indicies in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-indexing

I'm new to programming and I've created a simple *tic-tac-toe* game. It took an input of the row and column of a 2d array. However, I want to make it simpler and use a value of `1-9` instead to represent each square on the board.

The way I've gone about this seems rather long and complex. Sorry about the bad formatting since I wanted to save space.

```java
if (pos >= 0 && pos <= 9) { //checks if number is a valid position on the board
    if (pos == 1 && board[0][0] == ' ') { board[0][0] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 2 && board[0][1] == ' ') { board[0][1] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 3 && board[0][2] == ' ') { board[0][2] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 4 && board[1][0] == ' ') { board[1][0] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 5 && board[1][1] == ' ') { board[1][1] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 6 && board[1][2] == ' ') { board[1][2] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 7 && board[2][0] == ' ') { board[2][0] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 8 && board[2][1] == ' ') { board[2][1] = xo; return true; }
    if (pos == 9 && board[2][2] == ' ') { board[2][2] = xo; return true; }
}
return false;
```

The inner if statements check if the index is empty and then assigns the `x` or `o` depending on the number entered. If anyone knows any 'cleaner' and easier ways of doing this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

- `/` - Division operator
- `%` - Remainder operator

You can get the coordinates of the cell `[i][j]` without loops at all, using only one variable `pos` in the range from `1` to `9`:

```java
public static boolean isValid(int pos, char xo) {
    int i = (pos - 1) / 3; // row
    int j = (pos - 1) % 3; // column
    if (board[i][j] == ' ') {
        board[i][j] = xo;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much more convenient to use arrays for such things. I would do something like this:

```java
int p = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (p == pos && board[i][j] == ' ') {
            board[i][j] = xo;
            return true;
            p += 1;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int count = 1; //value of pos
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        char ch = board[i][j]; //setting that board value to ch
        if (pos == count && ch == ' ') {
            board[i][j] = xo; //that board value becomes xo
            return true; //returns true
        }
        count++;
    }
}
return false;
```