# Check if all characters in string are the same with inbuilt methods without loops

Tags: java, string, character

How can I build a Java method that returns `TRUE` if all the characters in a `String` are the same using inbuilt methods - without using Regex, loops, or recursion?

Examples:

```
aaaaaa --> True
abaaaa --> False
Aaaaaa --> False
```

Comment: take the first character, for example in `abaaa` count ihow many a's are present in `str.length()` if its equal it consist of all same character if not then `return false`

Comment: Why without a loop? You have to somehow iterate all the characters; and recursion would be an awful way to do this.

Comment: I do not think its possible without a loop. You might find some fancy in-built method, but it would also employ some loop of its own.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's a little challenge for a class, I believe the goal is to learn about built-in methods and method chaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the string to an `IntStream` using `.chars()` and check if the stream has distinct count of **1** using `.distinct().count() == 1`.

```
String s = "aaaaaa";
boolean isAllCharsSame = s.chars().distinct().count() == 1;
```

`isAllCharsSame` will be `true` if all characters in the string `s` are same, otherwise `false`.

Edit:

```
String s = "aaaaaa";
boolean isAllCharsSame = s.codePoints().distinct().count() == 1;
```

`.chars()` won't work for Unicode codepoints like `""`, use `.codePoints()` for that. Thanks to @BasilBourque for pointing this out.

Comment: Fails for an input of `""`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```java
String s = "aaaaaaa";
boolean same = s.replaceAll("" + s.charAt(0), "").length() == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
if ( "".codePoints().distinct().count() == 1 ) { … }
```

## Code point, not `char`

Some of the other Answers use `char`. Unfortunately the `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the 143,859 characters in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_planes_and_blocks). Just try using the string `""` instead of `"aaa"`.

Instead use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

```java
Set < Integer > codePointsDistinct = "aaaaaaa".codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.toSet());
boolean allSameCharacter = ( codePointsDistinct.size() == 1 ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/TC61ts).

> true

We can make that even more brief by asking the stream to eliminate duplicates by calling [`.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()).

```
boolean allSameCharacter = ( "".codePoints().distinct().count() == 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a loop at all, using recursion. It's awful, but possible:

```
boolean singleChar(String s) {
  // Add check to make sure there is at least one char.

  char first = s.charAt(0);
  return singleCharRecursive(first, 1, s);
}

boolean singleCharRecursive(char first, int idx, String s) {
  return idx >= s.length()
      || (s.charAt(idx) == first && singleCharRecursive (first, idx+1, s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer

I believe there maybe another option analyzing off the first character in the string to see if they all match, but this one works.

```
String t = "aaa";
char c = t.charAt(0);
long cnt = t.chars().filter(ch -> ch == c).count();
System.out.println(cnt==t.length());
```

Comment: You can also do this.  `boolean result = t.chars().allMatch(ch -> ch == t.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method:

```java
boolean r = "aaaaaaa".replace("a", "").length() == 0;
System.out.println(r); // true
```

---

<sup>See also: [Easier way to represent indicies in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836781/15495739)</sup>